# How to rewrite /?blabla to another url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How to rewrite with .htaccess

```
?p_action=user_profile to /user
```

It seems to ignore the "?" character and I dont know what to do....

### Thanks

Some more details: ( my question has expanded now... :P)

I have `www.example.com/?p_action=user_profile&post_author=34`
and I want the browser to show `www.example.com/nice_url`
When I enter either the "ugly" or the "nice" url in the browser.

I.e. in case I enter `www.example.com/nice_url` , I want url_rewrite to happen, 
In case I enter www.example.com/?p_action=user_profile&post_author=34, I want it to e redirected to `www.example.com`.

The problem: I could nod rewrite the "?" mark, but I overcame it (luckily).

Now this is the code I have:

```
RewriteRule ^nice_url$  ?p_action=user_profile&post_author=34 [L]       

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  p_action=user_profile&post_author=34
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.example.co.il/nice_url?    [R=301,L]
```

HOWEVER, this creates a loop...

I tried adding this

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 #looks if there was a redirect
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

But it did not help. I guess this is because I am using Wordpress and there are already some redirects...

Please help. How can I make my browser always show "www.example.com/nice_url"?

Thanks!

Comment: please give some more info.

Answer (score 1):

Add the redirect status condition directly to the rule.

```
RewriteRule ^nice_url$  ?p_action=user_profile&post_author=34 [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  p_action=user_profile&post_author=34
RewriteRule .*  http://www.example.co.il/nice_url?    [R=301,L]
```

This prevents messing up other WordPress rules as well.